# Object.getPrototypeOf fail to __proto__ fail to object.constructor.prototype shims

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototype, es5-shim

I have been looking through some shim/polyfill libraries and see that some of them have a shim for `Object.getPrototypeOf`. On fail to exist they fall through to using `__proto__` and if that doesn't exist then to `object.constructor.prototype`.

I understand that `__proto__` is "non-standard" and while slightly different to the `Object.getPrototypeOf` method, they can be pretty interchangeable.

I also understand that in principle the externally accessible `object.constructor.prototype` would suffice in many situations where neither of the other two existed (provided the prototype has not been reassigned).

Where I have a problem is with the following examples:

```
    function findPropertyOwner(object, property) {
        var count = 0;

        do {
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                return [object, count];
            }

            object = Object.getPrototypeOf(object);
            count += 1;
        } while (object);

        return undefined;
    }
```

Or

```
    function instanceOf(object, constructor) {
        while (object) {
            if (object === constructor.prototype) {
                return true;
            }

            object = Object.getPrototypeOf(object);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

With such examples as above where we "walk the chain" so to speak, if the shim falls back to `object.constructor.prototype` then we now end up in the horrible situation of an infinite loop.

My question: Is there any way to achieve the above code in an environment where `Object.getPrototypeOf` and `__proto__` do not exist?

My feeling is that there is not, but I just want to check in case there is some information out there that I have not come across.

Comment: I still don't get it why people call `__proto__` deprecated. It may have been deprecated, but AFAIK it is currently in a normative section of the ES6 draft. http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-B.3.1

Comment: Best you could probably do would be to keep a list of prototype objects encountered, and check the list for circular references. If one is found, either jump to `Object.prototype`, or just `return false`.

Comment: And this: `while (object !== undefined && object !== null) {` ...is unnecessarily long. Just do this: `while (object != null) {` ...and it'll test both `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: can you provide some more information ? maybe on jsfiddle...

Comment: @Fabrício Matté I was aware of the discussion, I will change the wording to ´non-standard´, like on the MDN page.

Comment: @squint I guess a reference of encountered prototypes would be the only solution and the line could be shortened to ´while (object) {´ I suppose :)

Comment: @Givi I don't think you want me to point you to an infinite loop jsfiddle?

Comment: Yeah, true since a prototype can't be a primitive, except for `null`. For a minute I was thinking that you might have the same issue with `__proto__`, but I did a quick test, and it seems that cyclical prototype chains are caught for you... which is nice!

Comment: @squint I tried keeping the references and jumping to ´Object.prototype´ and while this solves the circular prototype chains problem, the results are only correct for roughly 90% of the cases that I tried. An example fail would be ´instanceOf(new TypeError(), Error);´ gives false. And as much as I have tried, I can only conclude that the above examples will only work with access to the internal prototype i.e. ´Object.getPrototypeOf´ or ´__proto__´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments by @squint I will present the solution that I tried. I reworked the general shim for `Object.getPrototypeOf` that seems to be common among the libraries, based on [a blog by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/objectgetprototypeof/) as far as I can tell.

> **Cross-Browser Implementation**
>
> The obvious question now becomes: How do we begin using
>   Object.getPrototypeOf today if most browsers don’t have it implemented
>   yet? In the meantime we can use something like the following code for
>   some form of compatibility:
>
> ```
> if (typeof Object.getPrototypeOf !== "function") {
>     if (typeof "test".__proto__ === "object") {
>         Object.getPrototypeOf = function (object) {
>             return object.__proto__;
>         };
>     } else {
>         Object.getPrototypeOf = function (object) {
>             // May break if the constructor has been tampered with
>             return object.constructor.prototype;
>         };
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> While it’s not 100% spot-on (since the .constructor property is
>   mutable on any object – it’s fully possible that it could’ve been
>   manipulated by the user at some point) the above code should serve as
>   a “good enough” solution to tide you over until browsers have good
>   ECMAScript 3.1 compatibility.

And this is what I came up with

```
if (typeof Object.getPrototypeOf !== "function") {
    if (Object.prototype.__proto__ === null) {
        Object.getPrototypeOf = function getPrototypeOf(object) {
            return object[proto];
        };
    } else {
        Object.getPrototypeOf = function getPrototypeOf(object) {
            if (object === Object.prototype) {
                return null;
            }

            if (object === object.constructor.prototype) {
                return Object.prototype;
            }

            return object.constructor.prototype;
        };
    }
}
```

As I mentioned in my comments, this solves the circular prototype chain problem that I experienced with the John Resig version.

The problem that I do have with it (other than it may break if the constructor has been tampered with) is that during my tests I found that I get false result on one particular test (there may be more, but not that I have yet found). The test/s concern the [Error objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

**instanceof**

```
new TypeError() instanceof Error; // --> true
```

**function instanceOf with ES5 Object.getPrototypeOf or _*proto*_**

```
instanceOf(new TypeError(), Error); // --> true
```

**function instanceOf with object.constructor.prototype fallthrough**

```
instanceOf(new TypeError(), Error); // --> false
```

All my other testing gave me matching results, but as I said, there may be more inconsistencies out there (where the constructor has not been tampered with). This is the best that I have managed to come up with, but at least I no longer have the possibility of infinite loops on functions similar to those given in my question.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/xTLuV/) that demonstrates the problem. (tested on Chromium v25, FireFox v20 and Opera 12.14: they are all that I have available)